# Slack App Development with firebase cloud functions and bolt library

Tags: google-cloud-functions, slack-api, bolts-framework

Bolt library doesn't work when deploying on Faas (Functions as a service) highlighted in the issue (https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/issues/361)

There is a workaround for AWS Lambda, as specified in the github issue. Is there a similar workaround when deploying on firebase cloud functions.

Comment: I see a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/seratch/bolt-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase) where Bolt app is running with Cloud functions for Firebase. Can you check if this works for you? If no, please elaborate your use case with code details or how you are integrating these with one another?

Comment: Hey, I had moved this to Heroku, but thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ExpressReceiver` from `@slack/bolt` package. It works well with firebase functions context. Just like Express

```js
import { App, ExpressReceiver } from '@slack/bolt'

const expressReceiver = new ExpressReceiver({...})
const app = new App({ receiver: expressReceiver })

export const myFunction = region('europe-west1')
  .https.onRequest(expressReceiver.app)
```